# Questions on how to write a function allLessThan in ML?

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

Write a function `allLessThan`. It takes two list of integers and test if all integers in the first list are less than all integers in the second list.

For example `allLessThan([2,4], [6,7,8])` would return true

I've tried to set up the function in terms of letting the sets equal `xx` and `yy` so that if every element in `xx` is less than every element in `yy` then the function would return true, but if not would return false.

```
- fun allLessThan([], yy) = true
=  | allLessThan(xx, []) = false
=  | allLessThan(x::xRest, y::yRest)
```

Comment: It's very tricky to recurse over two lists at once. Think about how much easier it would be to write this if you already had a function that determined whether a single integer was less than all elements in a list.

Comment: @molbdnilo yea I wish it would be that way but my teacher is a stickler and wants us to do it with 2 list at once. And she isn’t very helpful either

Comment: Has your teacher actually said that you're not allowed to use any "helper" functions? If you had the function I mentioned, this function would be a very simple recursion. It's also possible that this is an exercise in using `map`s, `fold`s, and/or `filter`s, in particular if you've learned about those recently. (Your teacher is probably unhelpful because it's very difficult to provide any help at all without providing the entire solution, which is extremely unhelpful. In my experience, most homework can be solved if you look through your lecture notes and previous exercises for ideas.)

Comment: @TheMathDude92: What molbdnilo was hinting at when saying *if you already had a function that determined whether a single integer was less than all elements in a list* is that if you make such a function, you could use it in `allLessThan`.

Comment: @SimonShine we don’t. I can go through the book where we had divisor one but it didn’t help too much.

Comment: @SimonShine the only function that is in the book is allHaveDivisor.

Comment: @TheMathDude92: If you make this, let's call it `singleLessThan : int -> int list -> Bool`, you would have it. You're allowed to make other functions than exactly the one you need. If you happen to make a function that solves a sub-part of a problem, you can use it in defining other functions.

Comment: One way to approach this problem is to write helper functions to compute mins and maxes of int lists. Apply these helper functions to the two lists, to check if the max of the first list is less than the min of the second.